# How wappalyzer(Mozila addon),GTmetrix finds the cms platform

Tags: browser

I am currently developing a site which is not supposed to expose its developer magento platform(Sorry about that ).

I thought the  wappalyzer(Mozila addon),GTmetrix site is finding the cms names by its html format but when i saw a empty white page with that tools it still shows me like am using Magento(there is nothing in the source view - its white page), so now how they are finding that am using magento. Any idea about hw they are working? I checked headers but there nothing specially mentioned as magento. Same goes with wordpress/joomla - simply  wappalyzer(Mozila addon),GTmetrix  finds the site platform even there is no html source.

So I guess something with in header(i might missing something) or what it can be? please advice. Attached screenshot of it.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Ela have you been able to solve this? If not what issues you faced, can you please elaborate we are also having a situation where client wants to hide the fact that the website uses magento. Thanking in anticipation. 

We have already got rid of all magento occurrences in our page source like mage / varien  etc we still however have a cookie named frontend which possibly is helping in recognizing magento. Further help may help us solve this.

Answer (score 6):

You can view Wappalyzer's source code: (Ctrl+F Magento):

https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer/blob/master/share/js/apps.js

Most likely Wappalyzer picked up on the "Mage" JavaScript variable. You can see this by clicking the DOM tab in Firebug.

Comment: Thanks for the Wappalyzer github link. I did it the same-thing - renamed all js,css classes and paths.

Comment: You'd have to change all occurrences of "Mage" and "VarienForm" in all JavaScript files, which will be a challenge. Even if you do that there will be plenty of other ways to identify Magento. (I wrote Wappalyzer.)

Answer (score 1):

They are finding it using the words like mage,varien,magento. If it finds any of these words inside css/js file class,#id,inside comment then it found it as magento.

Also gtmetrix does one more step , like it is checking the css/js url path - if it fins the url like skin/frontend then it says it as magento.

Comment: i tried to replace all the names with another word but it still recognizes it. is there any good solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget cookies...

I use FireBugs. Go to main menu -> Cookies

There is `frontend` in cookies.